# Installing wget and werkzeug in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, spyder

I am new to the Spyder environment and need help in installing the two packages in Spyder.

I try to run `pip install wget` in the IPython console but it returns the error -

```
/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/MacOS/python: No module named pip \
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

I'm currently using the Default interpreter in Spyder. 
What is the general procedure to install packages like `bs4` or other external packages in Spyder IDE?

Comment: As far as I am aware, you cannot install packages via Spyder, (this is not PyCharm/VSCode, and thank goodness for that!) this must be done via the *command line* using `pip`.

Comment: I have installed ```wget``` using my terminal. I tried installing it using IPython Console in Spyder using ```!pip install wget``` but I'm getting the error ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'```

Comment: Ok, have you tried installing `encodings`?  Should be something like `pip install encodings`; off the top of my head.

Comment: I did. It shows the same error ```ModuleNotFoundError: No moduled named 'encodings'```